# Typescript how to augment Object class?

Tags: typescript, module-augmentation

I am familiar with the Kotlin extension function `let` (and related) (cf. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html).

I wanted to use something similar in TypeScript, using augmentation (or is it called declaration merging?). So I thought I can add the `let` method to the `Object` superclass.

How can I do it? I thought of something like the following, but that didn't work. Typescript doesn't seem to augment, but to solely use the following interface.

```ts
interface Object {
  let<T, R>(block: (t: T) => R): R
}

(Object.prototype as any).let = function<T, R>(block: (t: T) => R) {
  return block(this)
}
```

**EDIT:**

Test cases would be:

```ts
'42'.let(it => alert(it))
'foo'.let(it => it.toUpperCase())
```

(i. e. `let` would be available on any objects, in this case strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

```js
interface Object {
  let<T, R>(this: T, block: (t: T) => R): R;
}

Object.prototype.let = function <T, R>(this: T, block: (t: T) => R): R {
  return block(this);
};

'42'.let(it => alert(it)); // let -> Object.let<string, void>(this: string, block: (t: string) => void): void
(42).let(it => alert(it)); // let -> Object.let<number, void>(this: number, block: (t: number) => void): void
'foo'.let(it => it.toUpperCase()); // let -> Object.let<string, string>(this: string, block: (t: string) => string): string
['foo'].let(it => it[0].toUpperCase()); // let -> Object.let<string[], string>(this: string[], block: (t: string[]) => string): string
```

[codepan](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFmQbwChlkAbCMAHgBUAaZAJQD4AKMAC2AGcAuZO5OlIB7BAGs+bPtQCUyALxNGMvgwDchAL6FCGbLgB0AByjCwZgJ5GIB8nnnIYAVxC5gwkMhr1mbTr356IVEJZCl+OUVlVQJiZCgKJyhPYPE-bhkNTQ1CAHIAFgAmXNsKFmB7JThyKDBysBlM5AB6ZrIKZABaJT0cMFKqLjAoUABzegA3YWAAE1YObj4hkZBxwRFxSTAl4bHIpSnZlWRDmcIWIpkB+oUqmrqKxrUWtrsunqw+gcoQJwBbdDQSbTObpAK-AFA9YhLZ8CGAqD7E4g46nPIwYTCEp2G5RCoGcwAVSM1igAGE4FwICwni92nhumhPoY7JRlmN6OzVvN-DsVmtUqFwlzRkiRccRYQANq5DFYgC61wqt2QFSlAAZFUSSdAKVSaU1WvT3kz9P1WSKpfLObtuWC+WMrUENkLtshLfKxbbRQ7VkA)

**EDIT 1**

Updated the above to reflect better typing of the `this` argument +  examples

**EDIT 2**

### Explanation

1. declaring `let` on the `Object` interface merges that declaration with the rest of the `Object` interface. See [Declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)
2. In case this declaration is in a module (a file with `import` and/or `export`) you do the declaration in a global scope:

   ```js
   declare global {
     interface Object {
       ...
     }
   }
   ```

   See [Global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation)
3. Using the `this` argument in the method declaration declares the type of `this` in the method signature. See [Polymorphic `this`types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types)
4. TypeScript needs a way to implicitly understand the specific type, to do so, we'll use generics. See [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)
5. Putting all of the above together, by declaring `method<T>(this: T)`, we make TypeScript know that the `this` argument should take the form of the type the method is executed on. That way, if the method exists on a type (and it does, since we augmented the `Object` interface), using it on that type causes the `this` argument to be of that type.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for pointing out the `this` handling. However, testing your code with the line `'42'.let(it => alert(it))` works in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/, but does not work with my  tsc` compiler. Both versions are 3.8.3 any idea?

Comment: Note: I had to write `(Object.prototype as any)` because otherwise my typescript compiler won't accept defining `let` on `Object.prototype`.

Comment: The error message is `error TS2339: Property 'let' does not exist on type '"42"'.`

Comment: @fjf2002 if you cast `Object.prototype` to `any` this would not work and will give you the error you're showing. If you're not able to define `let` on the `Object.prototype` it is because you're not merging the `Object` interface. Is this code in a module (does the file have `import` or `export`)? if so, you need to wrap the interface merging with a `declare global` scope. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, the `declare global` thing was essential. The cast to `any` did not matter, as it didn't on the typescript playground example. But `'foo'.let(it => it.toUpperCase())` now has the problem that `it` has type `Object`, not type string. Any idea?

Comment: There must be some reason why the code does not behave as claimed in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types

Comment: Do you have any explanation or link to the docs why using this-type did not use the subtype, but type-parametrizing with T and using the fake this-parameter `this: T` does !?

Comment: @fjf2002 you provided the link above ;) it was just a matter of understanding how to use it right. I'll add explanation to the answer

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation :-)